# Can't I set a variable at property url mx:HTTPService?

Tags: apache-flex, variables, httpservice

I build an application that need httpservice feature. This application will be deployed at some computer. So, I don't have an idea to set variable at url property.

```
  <mx:HTTPService id="personRequest" url="http://118.97.239.36/dokeos/main/webservices/send_sip.php"
     useProxy="false" method="GET" resultFormat="text" result="personJSON(event)">
    <mx:request xmlns="">
      <getPerson>"true"</getPerson>
    </mx:request>
  </mx:HTTPService>
```

I already try with block {}, but no use.

Can't I set a variable at property url mx:HTTPService?

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using actionscript because you can then use the same service over and over but sending different data:

```
personRequest.send({getPerson:true});
```

Comment: so, how about the ip address? I need a change occasionally.

Comment: I normally just create one HTTPService per URL and call it different things like personService, authService, etc.  You should also look into a command pattern to make things simpler.